# Eigen::Affine3d Rotation Unexpected Result

Tags: c++, eigen

My test method is as following:

```
    TEST_METHOD(RotationTest1)
    {
        std::stringstream log;
        Eigen::Affine3d t(
            Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 4, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ())*
            Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 8, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY())
            );
        log << "Expected:\n" << t.rotation();

        Eigen::Affine3d act;
        act = Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 4, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ())*
            Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 8, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY()) * act;
        //act.prerotate(Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 8, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY()));
        //act.prerotate(Eigen::AngleAxisd(M_PI / 4, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ()));
        log << "\nActual:\n" << act.rotation();
        Logger::WriteMessage(log.str().c_str());
        Assert::IsTrue(t.rotation().isApprox(act.rotation()));
    }
```

This produced the following inconsistent output:

```
Expected:
 0.653281 -0.707107  0.270598
 0.653281  0.707107  0.270598
-0.382683         0   0.92388
Actual:
-0.756394  0.645492  -0.10587
-0.324051 -0.510375  -0.79656
-0.568206 -0.568206  0.595217
```

Can somebody explain to me the above behaviour, please?

Answer (score 0):

I did not set the transformation to identity before attempting any other transformation. To fix it add the line after default construct:

```
Eigen::Affine3d act;
act.setIdentity();
```

Or construct with the identity matrix:

```
Eigen::Affine3d act(Eigen::Affine3d::Identity());
```

Comment: Or simply remove the act instance at the right of the product chain.